# How to configure Nautilus 3 toolbar in Debian Wheezy?

Tags: nautilus, debian

I'm using Debian Wheeze and I would like to configure the default Nautilus 3.4.2 toolbar. Basically, I would like to add some buttons such as the *Open parent* button which can be accomplished with the keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>.

In Nautilus 2.x it is present in the toolbar and also in the menu and it has an icon in the menu. The icon is present in 3.x too but for some reason not present in the toolbar and I can't find any way to customize it.

This is the Nautilus 2.x I want to emulate (or at least add a few of those buttons):

[image: Nautilus 2]

This is the Nautilus 3.x I just can't edit:

[image: Nautilus 3]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you not have the gear icon? Much of what you want is under there now.

Comment: I like how *gear* sounds but I just don't see anything related to it. I also tried holding ALT while right clicking on the toolbar (similar to what gnome-panel expects for configuring) but I still had no luck.